# Why can't I declare C# methods virtual and static?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a helper class that is just a bunch of static methods and would like to subclass the helper class.  Some behavior is unique depending on the subclass so I would like to call a virtual method from the base class, but since all the methods are static I can't create a plain virtual method (need object reference in order to access virtual method).

Is there any way around this?  I guess I could use a singleton.. HelperClass.Instance.HelperMethod() isn't so much worse than HelperClass.HelperMethod().  Brownie points for anyone that can point out some languages that support virtual static methods.

**Edit:** OK yeah I'm crazy. Google search results had me thinking I wasn't for a bit there.

Comment: This kind of scenario means you should probably turn this into objects (not singletons).

Comment: I don't want to have to instantiate an object everywhere this helper method is used though.

Comment: Then use a singleton, or dependency injection, depending on which makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I have abstract static methods in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284/why-cant-i-have-abstract-static-methods-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement virtual static properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346631/how-to-implement-virtual-static-properties)

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/66070907/6053778) I describe a pattern that can emulate the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Virtual static methods don't make sense.  If I call `HelperClass.HelperMethod();`, why would I expect some random subclass' method to be called?  The solution really breaks down when you have 2 subclasses of `HelperClass` - which one would you use?

If you want to have overrideable static-type methods you should probably go with:

- A singleton, if you want the same subclass to be used globally.
- A tradition class hierarchy, with a factory or dependency injection, if you want different behavior in different parts of your application.

Choose whichever solution makes more sense in your situation.

Comment: -1 Because you forgot about generics. T.Add(leftT, rightT); has so much sense. Isn't it?

Comment: And how would you override your implementation in a subclass?

Comment: It could be implemented as a virtual instance member of the class' type. Subclasses' types would inherit from the class' type, allowing them to override.

Comment: Yes, but the subclass' implementation would not be available from the base type in a static context, which is what the original question asked.

Comment: Yes, they do make sense, it's just a matter of semantics. I'd argue that if it makes sense to declare a static method inside a class, it makes sense to allow overriding it on a per-type basis. See the Delphi examples in this thread.
You may argue that 'static' has a defined meaning; well, in C it has a very different meaning from C# and Java, for example.

Comment: @etrusco is right.  Other languages, like Python, have virtual static methods.  In those languages, the object is available for dynamic dispatch, but not passed to the method (since the method is static).

Comment: Yes it DOES make sense. This should not be marked as the answer.

Comment: This answer makes no sense and I can't understand how it has so many upvotes. Why would I expect `HelperClass.HelperMethod()` to call some random subclass' method any more than I would expect `helperInstance.HelperMethod()` to do so? It's just nonsensical. It makes perfect sense that I should be able to create a virtual static method. If it's called on the base class, it calls the base method. If it's called on the derived class, it calls the overridden method. It's precisely the same as if the methods were not static and I were making the calls using instances of the classes.

Answer (score 48):

I don't think you are crazy. You just want to use what is impossible currently in .NET.
Your request for virtual static method would have so much sense if we are talking about generics.
For example my future request for CLR designers is to allow me to write intereface like this:

```
public interface ISumable<T>
{
  static T Add(T left, T right);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
public T Aggregate<T>(T left, T right) where T : ISumable<T>
{
  return T.Add(left, right);
}
```

But it's impossible right now, so I'm doing it like this:

```
    public static class Static<T> where T : new()
    {
      public static T Value = new T();
    }

    public interface ISumable<T>
    {
      T Add(T left, T right);
    }

    public T Aggregate<T>(T left, T right) where T : ISumable<T>, new()
    {
      return Static<T>.Value.Add(left, right);
    }
```

Comment: @SeeR: -1: I'll correct that if I'm wrong, but this doesn't solve the original problem.

Comment: @John Saunders: He want static virtual methods, but it's impossible - He must use instance methods for it. He also don't want to instantiate this class everytime he want to use this static (now instance) methods - this is why I created Static<T> class. Now he will only have only one instance of his class for the whole application. I think it's acceptable tax for such functionality. Aggregate<T> method is just an example how he can use it. So in summary we have static virtual replacement in c# - wasn't that the request in question?

Comment: @SeeR: Your approach works fine if the type in question satisfies a `new` constraint.  Static virtual methods would allow such constructs to be used in type-safe fashion with types that didn't satisfy a `new` constraint.  Alternatively, one could have the `Static` class not have a `new` constraint, but rather attempt to use Reflection to create an object with a special parameterized constructor.  Unfortunately, I don't know any way to make that type-safe.

Answer (score 21):

You can achieve the same effect by just having a regular static method and then shadow it with the `new` keyword

```
public class Base 
{
    //Other stuff

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

public class SomeClass : Base
{
    public new static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeClass");
    }
}
public class SomeOtherClass : Base
{
}
```

Then you can call the methods like so

```
Base.DoSomething(); //Base
SomeClass.DoSomething(); //SomeClass
SomeOtherClass.DoSomething(); //Base
```

Comment: This might have unintended consequences.  For instance, if in your base class you have another method that calls DoSomething, and you call SomeClass.ThatOtherMethod(), that method calls the base's DoSomething, not the SomeClass's version. https://dotnetfiddle.net/scRWKD

Comment: throw NotImplementedException in the base class to make sure nothing calls this

Answer (score 16):

Indeed, this can be done in Delphi. An example:

```pascal
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  end;

  TTestClass = class
  public
    class procedure TestMethod(); virtual;
  end;

  TTestDerivedClass = class(TTestClass)
  public
    class procedure TestMethod(); override;
  end;

  TTestMetaClass = class of TTestClass;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

class procedure TTestClass.TestMethod();
begin
  Application.MessageBox('base', 'Message');
end;

class procedure TTestDerivedClass.TestMethod();
begin
  Application.MessageBox('descendant', 'Message');
end;


procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  sample: TTestMetaClass;
begin
  sample := TTestClass;
  sample.TestMethod;
  sample := TTestDerivedClass;
  sample.TestMethod;
end;
```

Quite interesting. I no longer use Delphi, but I recall being able to very easily create different types of controls on a custom designer canvas using the metaclass feature: the control class, eg. TButton, TTextBox etc. was a parameter, and I could call the appropriate constructor using the actual metaclass argument.

Kind of the poor man's factory pattern :)

Comment: The fact that c# does not support static virtual methods drives me crazy... especially considered that c# has been designed by the same guy who designed delphi 10 years before (Anders Hejlsberg)

Answer (score 9):

I come from Delphi and this is a feature among many that I sorely miss in c#.  Delphi would allow you to create typed type references and you could pass the type of a derived class wherever the type of a parent class was needed.  This treatment of types as objects had powerful utility.  In particular allowing run time determination of meta data.  I am horribly mixing syntax here but in c# it would look something like:

```
    class Root {
       public static virtual string TestMethod() {return "Root"; }
    }
    TRootClass = class of TRoot; // Here is the typed type declaration

    class Derived : Root {
       public static overide string TestMethod(){ return "derived"; }
    }

   class Test {
        public static string Run(){
           TRootClass rc;
           rc = Root;
           Test(rc);
           rc = Derived();
           Test(rc);
        }
        public static Test(TRootClass AClass){
           string str = AClass.TestMethod();
           Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
```

> would produce: 
>   Root 
>   derived

Answer (score 7):

a static method exists outside of an instance of a class. It cannot use any non-static data.

a virtual method will be "overwritten" by an overloaded function depending of the **type** of an instance.

so you have a clear contradiction between static and virtual.

This is not a problem of support, It is a concept.

**Update:** I was proven wrong here(see comments):

> So I doubt you will find any OOP-Language which will support virtual
>   static methods.

Comment: A virtual method can be overwritten on the type of the instance. All subclasses can share the same implementation of the overloaded function. That's why you want to make them BOTH static and virtual. That's late static binding, available in PHP5.

Comment: No, there is no contradiction, it is entirely a matter of compiler support, and many languages like Python do it.  They do it by having first-class classes. That is, classes that are themselves objects that can be assigned to variables and have their methods called. (Search for "classmethod" to learn more.)

Comment: Object Pascal (Delphi and the open source Lazarus equivalent) have always supported them

Answer (score 7):

You are not crazy. What you are referring to is called Late Static Binding; it's been recently added to PHP. There's a great thread that describes it - here: [When would you need to use late static binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87192/when-would-you-need-to-use-late-static-binding#87351)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to force an inheritance of "abstract static" methods from an abstract generic class. See as follow :

```
public abstract class Mother<T> where T : Mother<T>, new()
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();

    public static void Do()
    {
        (new T()).DoSomething();
    }

}

public class ChildA : Mother<ChildA>
{
    public override void DoSomething() { /* Your Code */ }
}

public class ChildB : Mother<ChildB>
{
    public override void DoSomething() { /* Your Code */ }
}
```

Example (using the previous Mother):

```
public class ChildA : Mother<ChildA>
{
    public override void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("42"); }
}

public class ChildB : Mother<ChildB>
{
    public override void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("12"); }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ChildA.Do();  //42
        ChildB.Do();  //12
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It's not that great since you can inherit from only one abstract class and it will ask you to be lenient with your new() implementation.

More, I think it will be costly memory-wise depending on the size of your inherited classes.
In case you have memory issue, you would have to set every properties/variables after your new in a public method which is an awful way to have default values.

Answer (score 1):

I heard that Delphi suports something like this. It seems it does it by making classes object instances of a metaclass.

I've not seen it work, so I'm not sure that it works, or what's the point for that.

P.S. Please correct me if I'm wrong, since it's not my domain.

Answer (score 1):

Because a virtual method uses the defined type of the instantiated object  to determine which implementation to execute, (as opposed to the declared type of the reference variable)

... and static, of course, is all about not caring if there's even an instantiated instance of the class at all...

So these are incompatible.

Bottom line, is if you want to change behavior based on which subclass an instance is, then the methods should have been virtual methods on the base class, not static methods.

But, as you already have these static methods, and now need to override them, you can solve your problem by this:
Add virtual instance methods to the base class that simply delegate to the static methods, and then override those virtual instance wrapper methods (not the static ones) in each derived subclass, as appropriate...

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to combine virtual and static for a method or a member by using the keyword `new` instead of `virtual`.

Here is an example:

```
class Car
{
    public static int TyreCount = 4;
    public virtual int GetTyreCount() { return TyreCount; }
}
class Tricar : Car
{
    public static new int TyreCount = 3;
    public override int GetTyreCount() { return TyreCount; }
}

...

Car[] cc = new Car[] { new Tricar(), new Car() };
int t0 = cc[0].GetTyreCount(); // t0 == 3
int t1 = cc[1].GetTyreCount(); // t1 == 4
```

Obviously the `TyreCount` value could have been set in the overridden `GetTyreCount` method, but this avoids duplicating the value. It is possible to get the value both from the class and the class instance.

Now can someone find a really intelligent usage of that feature?

Comment: @Mart: I almost downvoted you until I realized you've just got a bad example. Instead of the static fields, change the example to use static methods, where the derived class calls the base class method, then does something more.

Answer (score 1):

Mart got it right with the 'new' keyword. 
I actually got here because I needed this type of functionality and Mart's solution works fine. In fact I took it one better and made my base class method abstract to force the programmer to supply this field.

My scenario was as follows:

I have a base class HouseDeed. Each House type is derived from HouseDeed must have a price.

Here is the partial base HouseDeed class:

```
public abstract class HouseDeed : Item
{
    public static int m_price = 0;
    public abstract int Price { get; }
    /* more impl here */
}
```

Now lets look at two derived house types:

```
public class FieldStoneHouseDeed : HouseDeed
{
    public static new int m_price = 43800;
    public override int Price { get { return m_price; } }
    /* more impl here */
}
```

and...

```
public class SmallTowerDeed : HouseDeed
{
    public static new int m_price = 88500;
    public override int Price { get { return m_price; } }
    /* more impl here */
}
```

As you can see I can access the price of the house via type SmallTowerDeed.m_price, and the instance new SmallTowerDeed().Price
And being abstract, this mechanism nags the programmer into supplying a price for each new derived house type.

Someone pointed how 'static virtual' and 'virtual' are conceptually at odds with one another. I disagree. In this example, the static methods do not need access to the instance data, and so the requirements that (1) the price be available via the TYPE alone, and that (2) a price be supplied are met.

Comment: This answer only seems tangentially related to the question. Also it is a somewhat poor example. m_price is an implementation detail and adds nothing by being part of HouseDeed. It would be much better to remove it from HouseDeed and make m_price private in both sub classes. Same result without the abuse of the 'new' keyword.

Comment: Metadata is not tangent. It is a related need. All overrides are implementation details. You could similarly argue that "for" adds nothing to the language because it has "if" and "goto".

Answer (score 1):

An override method provides a new implementation of a member that is inherited from a base class. The method that is overridden by an override declaration is known as the overridden base method. The overridden base method must have the same signature as the override method. 
You cannot override a non-virtual or static method. The overridden base method must be virtual, abstract, or override.

An override declaration cannot change the accessibility of the virtual method. Both the override method and the virtual method must have the same access level modifier.

You cannot use the new, static, or virtual modifiers to modify an override method.

An overriding property declaration must specify exactly the same access modifier, type, and name as the inherited property, and the overridden property must be virtual, abstract, or override.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new keyword

```
namespace AspDotNetStorefront
{
    // This Class is need to override StudioOnlineCommonHelper Methods in a branch
    public class StudioOnlineCommonHelper : StudioOnlineCore.StudioOnlineCommonHelper
    {
        //
        public static new void DoBusinessRulesChecks(Page page)
        {
            StudioOnlineCore.StudioOnlineCommonHelper.DoBusinessRulesChecks(page);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to simulate the functionality by using the **new** keyword in the derived class and throwing the **NotSupportedException()** in the base.

```
public class BaseClass{
    public static string GetString(){
        throw new NotSupportedException();   // This is not possible
    }
}

public class DerivedClassA : BaseClass {
    public static new string GetString(){
        return "This is derived class A";
    }
}

public class DerivedClassB : BaseClass {
    public static new string GetString(){
        return "This is derived class B";
    }
}

static public void Main(String[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DerivedClassA.GetString());  // Prints "This is derived class A"
    Console.WriteLine(DerivedClassB.GetString());  // Prints "This is derived class B"
    Console.WriteLine(BaseClass.GetString());      // Throws NotSupportedException
}
```

Due to the fact that it is not possible to detect this condition at compile time and that IntelliSense won't suggest that such function should be implemented in the derived class, this is a potential headache.

One comment also suggested to use **NotImplemetedException()**. Microsoft's documentation indicates that neither of these exceptions should be handled so any of them should work.

The differences between **NotSupportedException** and **NotImplemetedException** are commented in [this blog](https://blog.excastle.com/2004/10/15/notimplementedexception-vs-notsupportedexception/).

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to soon, in C# 11!

From [Tutorial: Explore C# 11 feature - static virtual members in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/static-virtual-interface-members):

> C# 11 and .NET 7 include *static virtual members in interfaces*. This feature enables you to define interfaces that include [overloaded operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) or other static members.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)