# OO Problem in C#

Tags: c#, oop

```
class Frame
{
    static int X;
    static int Y;
    static uint Color;

    static protected bool Check()
    {
        return (Coords.GetPixelColor(X, Y) == Color);
    }
}

class frameBeginning : Frame
{
    static int X = 1;
    static int Y = 2;
    static int Color = 3;
}
```

`frameBeginning.Check();` cannot compile, because `Check()` is inaccessible due to its protection level.

But why, `Check()` is protected?

Comment: siz is right. btw, you should use a coding standard. Generally, classes start with a capital letter. If you don't like that, at least be consistent everywhere (Frame vs frameBeginning).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a problem. The behavior you are seeing is part of the definition of [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). If you want to call frameBeginning.Check from outside the code of the frameBeginning or frame class, the method needs to be [public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx) or [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Because you declared it as protected in the code shown above.

But different rules apply to static methods. Check out the SO question below:

[C#: Can a base class use a derived class's variable in a static function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718372/c-can-a-base-class-use-a-derived-classs-variable-in-a-static-function)

Answer (score 2):

You could call `Check` from *within* `frameBeginning`, but not outside the class. This is what `protected` means: visible to derived classes, not to external code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `frameBeginning.Check()` from outside needs that `Check()` is public. Being protected is only visible to derived clasess, but not from outside. You're trying to access the `Check()` method from outside, so you need to do `Check()` public or internal.

In other words, you could acess `Check()` from a frameBeginning instance, but `Check()` is static, if you want to access Check() from outside, you need to change the visibility to public (or internal).

Answer (score 0):

So that the class itself and all inherited classes can use the method, independent of an instance of the object, but anything outside of the class can not use the method.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 access modifiers... you need to understand what kind of access you can get by each.

`private` - Function can only be called from within the class

`protected` - Function can be called only from within the class and all its derived classes

`internal protected` - Function can be called by the class and all its derived classes inside the **Assembly**

`internal` - Almost like public - Can be called from anywhere inside the **Assembly** ... Used for Incapsulation

`public` - Can be called from anywhere