# Converting object with explicit conversions to generic method type T

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have **AClass** which contains explicit conversions in form of methods:

```
public static explicit operator Double(AClass x)
```

for all primitive types: int, string, etc. Class does not implement *IConvertible* interface.

On top of this constraints I am making generic method which has following signature:

```
private void VerifyBla<T>(string abc, T expected)
```

AClass is basically wrapper arround primitive types, and in this method I would like to convert **AClass** to **T** and to verify it's value.

I have tried using:

```
(T)aClass
```

> but intelisense: Cannot convert type 'AClass' to T.

Is there any workaround how to solve this, with minimal or none changes to AClass?

I have tried using:

```
(T)Convert.ChangeType(myobject, typeof(T));
```

> but it failed because AClass is not implementing IConvertible. And if I would implement it, I would need to implement many methods I guess.

Comment: Does your wrapper hold a value field of Type T?

Comment: "AClass is not implementing IConvertible. And if I would implement it, I would need to implement many methods I guess." -- yes, but you already did the "hard" work of figuring out how to convert instances of `AClass` to the different types. So you're basically just calling these static operators from the interface methods. This sounds like a prime example to implement `IConvertible`.

Comment: As there´s no generic constraint for `T`, it can be **anything** including `MyClass`. And of course you can´t cast `AClass` to `MyClass`, as they don´t have any common inheritance-relation.

Comment: Technically, `(T)(dynamic)aClass` should work (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/16395840/87698), but that's not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement the full IConvertible interface, then it might make sense to do type pattern matching for only the few instances you have:

```
switch (expected)
{
    case Double dbl: return dbl == (Double)aClass;
    ...
}
```