# C# Interface determine implementation

Tags: c#, linq

I receive data from a DB. There will be only one model at a time which I call `currentModel` from now on. The type of model received must be determined at runtime. Therefore, I implemented an Interface for the models `IDataModel`. Each possible model implements `IDataModel`. There is a variable which holds the `currentModel`. In order to make it generic I defined it as `IDataModel`. Here is the code so far.

```
public async Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string sql, U parameters, string connectionString)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var rows = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sql, parameters);

        return rows.ToList();
    }
}

private IDataModel currentModel;
private List<IDataModel> queryResult;

if (someCondition)
{
    currentModel = newSpecificModel();
    sql = someQuery;
}
else ....

queryResult = await _data.LoadData<IDataModel, dynamic>(sql, new {}, config.GetConnectionString("default"));

if (queryResult.Count == 1)
{
    currentModel= queryResult.First();
}
else
{
    // Do error handling here if more than one row is returned from the query
}
```

Now when I try to access some property I get an error: `IDataModel does not contain a definition for someProperty`

```
currentModel.someProperty
```

How do I determine the current implementation at runtime?
I mean I could create a variable for each possible model. But is there a more elegant way?

**EDIT**

Nailed the problem down to that this wont work:

```
List<Interface> = List<Implementation>
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228173/c-sharp-listinterface-why-you-cannot-do-listifoo-foo-new-listbar).

Whats an approach to solve this?

Comment: *How do I determine the current implementation at runtime?* and what it will give you? ... your error is compile time error not runtime ... it `someProperty` is common for all `IDataModel` then move it into `IDataModel` ... if not ... you have to write different code for different classes

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern); it is useful for creating child objects with the right type.
Maybe also look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243836/c-sharp-virtual-static-method/27488287).

Comment: Please don't link to external sources without first putting the salient content in your answer. Links in answers should only provide supporting evidence.

Comment: Well, the name of the pattern is the real information here, summarizing it is not necessary, I think. Besides, the linked SO question / answer does that job.

Comment: No, not at all. You really should pay attention to those with a significant amount of rep here - we know how to help you to get more rep.

Comment: That is no motivation, just makes me feel patronized.