# Accessing property in class without instantiation

Tags: c#, class

Lets say I have a class:

```
public class foo
{

    public string bar 
    {
        get { return "A Value"; }
    }
}
```

If i only want to access the value contained in bar, and i wasn't interested in the actual class I could do something like:

```
string value = new foo().bar;
```

Is this really the best way of accessing the value? I don't want to make this property (and class) static.

If I had many classes with the bar property that I wanted to access, would there be a more generic way of doing it?

Edit: The reason why its not static is that its an overridden property, which i believe cannot be static:

```
public class parent
{
    public abstract string bar { get; }
}

public class foo : parent
{
    public override string bar
    {
        get { return "A Value"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you got against static classes?

Comment: Or indeed, a `static` property in a regular non-static class

Comment: @ShellShock Testability, dependency injection unfriendly etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I declare C# methods virtual and static?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248263/why-cant-i-declare-c-sharp-methods-virtual-and-static)

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `static` which allows for methods and properties without an instance:

```
public class foo
{
    public static string bar 
    {
        get { return "A Value"; }
    }
}
```

There's no other way (other than consts and that's limited in a sense) that I know of having non-instance members.

Comment: `public class foo()` I was just wondering: why the round brackets at the end of the class declaration?

Comment: @Lloyd `const`s are `static` (they work like it and compile to that in IL), they're just written without the `static` keyword.

Comment: @TimS Not exactly, you can only use value types IIRC? Static's allow you a bit more flexibility on that front (though you can drop in readonly as well).

Comment: @Lloyd true, I didn't mean that `const` is the same thing as `static`; just that if something is `const`, it is also `static`, though it doesn't use the `static` keyword.

Comment: Sorry all I have updated the original question to include the abstract property

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example I assume the value is a constant one, so instead of using a `static` property, you can use a `const` (which is about the same but more explicit):

```
public class Foo
{
    public const string Bar = "A value";
}
```

and access it with:

```
string value = Foo.Bar;
```

...*but it depends on what you want to do with this variable* - so maybe you can elaborate on that.

In any case, sometimes static **variables** have their uses, but don't overdo it. I personally always try to avoid statics as much as possible (in particular static operations) for a number of reasons, for example, see static facade in [this post](http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/patterns-to-be-avoided/).

Also note that public properties and class names should follow Pascal notation, so it should be `Bar` and `Foo`.

An alternative option is to inject a provider component that provides you with the value. The dependency injection container takes care of this, and you could specify the correct lifetime for it at startup of your application. The default implementation (which gets the value from a configuration file for example) could then easily be replaced. Again, it all depends how far you want to go with this and how complex this 'value' is, if it's only a string, keep it simple :)

Comment: Note that this only works if the value is simple and fixed, as in this example; if you actually need to run code to determine it, it should remain a property.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I added 'but it depends on what you want to do with this variable.'. if this question is answered, maybe we could elaborate :)