# Getting static property from a class with dynamic class name in PHP

Tags: php, oop, dynamic, static, properties

I have this:

- one string variable which holds the class name (`$classname`)
- one string variable with holds the property name (`$propertyname`)

I want to get that property from that class, the problem is, the property is static and I don't know how to do that.

If the property weren't static, it would have been:

```
$classname->$propertyname;
```

if the property were a method, I could have used call_user_function

```
call_user_func(array($classname, $propertyname));
```

But in my case, am I just lost. I am however hoping that it is possible. With the thousands of functions that PHP has, he'd better have something for this as well. Maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks!

Edit:

- for those with [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) solutions: thanks, but it is out of the question
- for those with [get _class _vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) solutions: thanks, but it seems it returns **"the default properties of the given class"** (php.net), and yes, I would like that value to be changable (even though it does help me in some of the cases)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.3.0 or greater, you can use the following:

```
$classname::$$propertyname;
```

<strike>Unfortunately, if you are using a version lower than 5.3.0, you are stuck using [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) ([`get_class_vars()`](http://php.net/get-class-vars) will not work if the value is dynamic).</strike>

```
$value = eval($classname.'::$'.$propertyname.';');
```

---

**EDIT:** I've just said [`get_class_vars()`](http://php.net/get-class-vars) wouldn't work if the value is dynamic, but apparently, variable static members are part of *"the default properties of a class"*. You could use the following wrapper:

```
function get_user_prop($className, $property) {
  if(!class_exists($className)) return null;
  if(!property_exists($className, $property)) return null;

  $vars = get_class_vars($className);
  return $vars[$property];
}

class Foo { static $bar = 'Fizz'; }

echo get_user_prop('Foo', 'bar'); // echoes Fizz
Foo::$bar = 'Buzz';
echo get_user_prop('Foo', 'bar'); // echoes Buzz
```

Unfortunately, if you want to set the value of the variable, you will still need to use [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval), but with some validation in place, it's *not so evil*.

```
function set_user_prop($className, $property,$value) {
  if(!class_exists($className)) return false;
  if(!property_exists($className, $property)) return false;

  /* Since I cannot trust the value of $value
   * I am putting it in single quotes (I don't
   * want its value to be evaled. Now it will
   * just be parsed as a variable reference).
   */
  eval($className.'::$'.$property.'=$value;');
  return true;
}

class Foo { static $bar = 'Fizz'; }

echo get_user_prop('Foo', 'bar'); // echoes Fizz
set_user_prop('Foo', 'bar', 'Buzz');
echo get_user_prop('Foo', 'bar'); // echoes Buzz
```

`set_user_prop()` with this validation **should** be secure. If people start putting random things as `$className` and `$property`, it will exit out of the function as it won't be an existing class or property. As of `$value`, it is never actually parsed as code so whatever they put in there won't affect the script.

Comment: Oh my god, I was just about to ask "but how about setting...". Dude, you totally rock!

Comment: In PHP 5 and up (I'm on 5.2), you can use reflection for this, as I just learned. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354628/from-the-string-name-of-a-class-can-i-get-a-static-variable/3364090#3364090

Comment: Shouldn't it be more like `classname::$propertyname;` in your first example, instead of `$classname::$$propertyname;`? Maybe this is just a typical version-thingy.

Comment: get_user_prop works for me. I wish the PHP Manual included it.

Comment: `$classname::${$propertyname};` also works and reads less like a typo I might accidentally "correct".

Answer (score 17):

I think this is the simplest:

```
$foo = new ReflectionProperty('myClassName', 'myPropertyName'); 
print $foo->getValue();
```

Answer (score 14):

To return a variable value that is set by a Static Variable you need to call:

```
$static_value = constant($classname.'::'.$propertyname);
```

Check out the documentation :: [PHP Constant Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php)

Comment: +1 for the hint. But i think it works only for class constants and not class static variables.

Comment: I tested, it does work ONLY with class constants, but NOT with class static variables.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. 10 points

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like:

```
eval("echo $classname::$propertyname;");
```

I just did a quick test and got this to work for me. Not sure if there's a better way or not, but I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: eval is evil :) never use it. there is always better alternatives

Comment: "Eval is evil" should be continued with "if you'r unsure of what you are doing" - obviously it can be useful as a last resort or it wouldn't be part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

'eval' looks so close to 'evil', and I hate using it and/or seeing it in code.  With a few ideas from other answers, here's a way to avoid it even if your php isn't 5.3 or higher.

Changed to reflect testing based on a comment.

```
class A {
    static $foo = 'bar';
}

A::$foo = 'baz';
$a = new A;

$class = get_class($a);
$vars = get_class_vars($class);

echo $vars['foo'];
```

Outputs 'baz'.

Comment: `get_class_vars()` only returns the initial value of `$foo`. If `$foo` changes, the value you will get from `get_class_vars()` will not change.

Comment: Actually, by definition it's not supposed to work, but apparently does.

Comment: I agree with your second comment.  I thought that was a little weird, so I tested it and updated my answer.  Does that match what you found?

Comment: Actually, `get_class_vars('A')` just works fine. You don't need to create an instance.

Comment: Sweet.  *<|:^)  <-- meeting minimum char limit with Santa.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed is that you can't set variables which are protected in static classes as the eval() command runs in a scope outside the class. The only thing to get around this would be to implement a static method inside the/every class which runs the eval(). This method could be protected as the call_user_func() [to call the setter method] also runs from inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially relevant: discussion on late static binding in PHP - [When would you need to use late static binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87192/when-would-you-need-to-use-late-static-binding).

Answer (score 0):

`get_class_vars` is not same as `get_object_vars`.

I think `get_clas_vars` should return the original property values.

Answer (score 0):

Even if for you said `eval` is out of the question, prior PHP 5.3 the easiest solution is still by using `eval`:

```
eval("\$propertyval = $classname::\$propertyname;");
echo $propertyval;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Getting and setting both static and non static properties without using Reflection

Using *Reflection* works but it is costly

Here is what I use for this purpose,

It works for **`PHP 5 >= 5.1.0`** because I'm using `property_exist`

```
function getObjectProperty($object, $property)
{
    if (property_exists(get_class($object), $property)) {
        return array_key_exists($property, get_object_vars($object))
            ? $object->{$property}
            : $object::$$property;
    }
}

function setObjectProperty($object, $property, $value)
{
    if (property_exists(get_class($object), $property)) {
        array_key_exists($property, get_object_vars($object))
            ? $object->{$property} = $value
            : $object::$$property = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't work with PHP<5.3 because `$object::$$property` is not valid syntax for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReflectionClass:

```
class foo
{
    private static $bar = "something";
}

$class = "foo";
$reflector = new ReflectionClass($class);
$static_vars = $reflector->getStaticProperties();
var_dump($static_vars["bar"]);
```