# PHP: Getting a value of a static variable of an unknown subclass

Tags: php, static-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [From the string name of a class, can I get a static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354628/from-the-string-name-of-a-class-can-i-get-a-static-variable)

Somewhere in a parent class, I need to find the value of a static variable of one of the possible child classes, determined by the current instance.

I wrote:

```
  $class = get_class($this);
  $value = isset($class::$foo['bar']) ? $class::$foo['bar'] : 5;
```

In this example, the subclass whose name is in `$class` has a public static $foo.

I know using `$class::$foo['bar']` is not a very beautiful piece of code, but it gets the job done on PHP 5.3.4.

In PHP 5.2.6 though, I am getting a syntax error:
*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting ',' or ')'*

Is there an alternative way that would work on PHP 5.2.4+ that would get the same thing done?

Comment: Good catch. Fixed it by using the solution provided there.

Comment: Hmm, original comment was removed. By "the solution provided there" I refer to the question that this is a duplicate of. See link above.

Comment: This kind of comments is created automatically when someone votes to close a question as duplicate. If the question is closed, the comment gets removed and the link is added to the top of the question, as you already saw...

Comment: Yep, I just found out. As that auto-comment disappeared when I voted to close my own question (i.e. putting up the last straw) my "reply" looked rather useless. Thanks for the explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Reflection is better.

You can try the `get_class_vars` method.  No access to PHP 5.2.6, but this works in 5.2.11...

```
class Test {
    public static $foo;

    function __construct() {
        echo("...Constructing...<br/>");
        Test::$foo = array();
        Test::$foo['bar'] = 42;
    }

    function __toString() {
        return "Test";
    }
}


$className = 'Test';
$class = new $className();

$vars = get_class_vars($className);

echo($vars['foo']['bar'] . "<br/>");
```

Output:

```
...Constructing...
42
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this does not work in PHP 5.2, is because before PHP 5.3 you are not allowed to use variables in the classname. So, if possible use `eval` for this.

```
eval('$result = ' . $c . '::$foo[\'bar\'];');
echo $result;
```

Otherwise, you're forced to use a function in the child class to receive the value. For example:

```
class MyParent {
    public function __construct() {
        $var = $this->_getVariable();
        echo $var['bar'];
    }
}

class MyChild extends MyParent {
    static $var = array('bar' => 'foo');

    protected function _getVariable() {
        return self::$var;
    }
}

new MyChild();
```

Comment: While this would work, I fixed it using the ReflectionProperty class in the SPL, which is accessible in PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Bar1 {
    static $var = array('index' => 'value');
}
class Bar2 extends Bar1 {
}
class Foo extends Bar2 {
    static $var = array('index' => 'value in Foo');
    public function __construct() {
        echo parent::$var['index'];
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
```

will output 'value', but not 'value in Foo'

Hope, that's what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I specifically want to access a variable in a subclass, not one in the superclass.

Comment: **Pelle ten Cate**, that's exactly what my code does. see updated code

Comment: I might be messing up terminology than. You are especially accessing a variable of Bar1 in class Foo. I wanted to do the opposite: assume both Foo and Bar2 has a public static variable $var, I want to access that in a function in class Bar1 that was called in one of the other classes.

Answer (score -1):

You can get class static/call static method in the class you are working in using `self` key word or for parent class using `parent`. You can get that error on php 5.2.6 because of changes in `get_class` function in PHP 5.3.0

Comment: No, the error is about late static binding, a syntax that was introduced in PHP 5.3. The behaviour of get_class hasn't changed if a parameter was specified. As said, I was looking for getting a variable in one of the subclasses, not in the superclass (`parent`) or `self`.