# How can I get a list of static variables in a class?

Tags: php, class, variables, reflection, static

With a class like

```
class MyClass {
    static var1 = "a";
    static var2 = "b";
}
```

... I'd like to retrieve the static members and their values at runtime; something like

```
Array(
    "var1" => "a",
    "var2" => "b"
)
```

Is there any way to do this in PHP?

Comment: I found get_class_vars(get_class($obj)), but that only works if $obj is an _instantiated_ object, not the class itself.  If I'll only have static members in my class, I'd like to keep from having to instantiate the class.

Comment: @Philip: You can edit your question and add the information you've placed in form of a comment much more nicely inside your question ;)

Comment: Related: [From the string name of a class, can I get a static variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354628/from-the-string-name-of-a-class-can-i-get-a-static-variable)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use [`ReflectionClass::getStaticProperties()`](http://php.net/manual/reflectionclass.getstaticproperties.php) to do this:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
$arr = $class->getStaticProperties();
```

```
Array
(
    [var1] => a
    [var2] => b
)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getstaticproperties.php - try this

getting information about classes and class properties such as all static methods is called "reflection".

Comment: [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). Please improve if possible.