# print_r shows private var. Why?

Tags: php, class, echo, private

Why can `print_r` see the private property *$version* even when its scope is set to *private*?

```
class myClass {

    private $version;

    public function set_version($value){
        $this->version = $value;
    }


}



$class = new myClass();
$class->set_version("1.2");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($class);
```

Comment: `private` object properties are primarily in the context of class inheritance, and internal scope, only.

Comment: Don't assume that `private` means "secure". It's only an indicator for how this property *should be used*, it doesn't provide any actual "security" or in fact "real privacy".

Comment: @deceze Private means that it's only in side the specific class there can read and update the value of the var or function. that why I was wondering about how the print_r still could see it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) shows private member properties for debugging purposes. It should not be used to output an object for display purposes (e.g. in a view/page). To display information about an object, it would likely be appropriate to create a method (e.g. *toString*) that will return the appropriate information.

> **print_r()**, [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) will also show protected and private properties of objects. Static class members will not be shown.<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#refsect1-function.print-r-description)</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#refsect1-function.print-r-description</sub>

Comment: Why not static class?

Comment: Thanks man! :D well @TheCrazyProfessor thats a good question.

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor I presume it is an internal storage thing... e.g. maybe PHP stores the static variables with the class definition in one object and then instances of that class are in a separate object... If you really want those, you could use a [Reflection class](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php) (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763994/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-static-variables-in-a-class#answer-8764052) for more info also)

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, as of PHP 5.6.0 you can use [__debugInfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo), which will allow you to override or refine what `print_r()`, `var_dump()` outputs.

So for example, using json encode and decode, you can return only the public properties.

```
<?php
class myClass {

    private $private_var;

    public $public_var = 'Foobar';

    public function setPrivate($value)
    {
        $this->private_var = $value;
    }

    public function __debugInfo()
    {
        return json_decode(json_encode($this), true);
    }
}

$class = new myClass();
$class->setPrivate("Baz");

print_r($class);
```

https://3v4l.org/seDI6

**Result:**

```
myClass Object
(
    [public_var] => Foobar
)
```