# accessing static methods using a variable class name (PHP)

Tags: php, variables, methods, static

I am trying to access a static method, but using a variable as the class name. Is this possible? I seem to be having issues with it. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
class foo {
    public static function bar() {
        echo 'test';
    }
}

$variable_class_name = 'foo';
$variable_class_name::bar();
```

And I want to be able to do similar using static variables as well.

Comment: This works fine for me on php 5.3.2.

Comment: using 5.2 i believe. get an error like "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /some/path/application/models/lev_base_model.php on line 35"

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?  As far as I'm aware you've been able to do this in recent versions (5.2+, though not exactly sure from when this would be valid)

Comment: @Gordon seems to only be allowed in 5.3+

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That syntax is only supported in PHP 5.3 and later. Previous versions don't understand that syntax, hence your parse error (`T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` refers to the `::` operator).

In previous versions you can try `call_user_func()`, passing it an array containing the class name and its method name:

```
$variable_class_name = 'foo';
call_user_func(array($variable_class_name, 'bar'));
```

Comment: looks great. Is there something similar for static properties?

Comment: @dqhendricks: not sure about class variables. For arguments, use `call_user_func()` with variadic arguments (like `sprintf()`), or use `call_user_func_array()` with an array of arguments. Both of these functions return the return values of the methods.

Comment: @dqhendricks: see ["Getting static property from a class with dynamic class name in PHP"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279081/getting-static-property-from-a-class-with-dynamic-class-name-in-php).

Answer (score 8):

You can use [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getstaticpropertyvalue.php) for PHP 5.1 and above:

```
class foo {
    public static $bar = 'foobar';
}

$class = 'foo';
$reflector = new ReflectionClass($class);
echo $reflector->getStaticPropertyValue('bar');

> foobar
```