# PHP 5.5: accessing a static class member of a dynamic class stored in an object

Tags: php, variables, static

We assume the following:

```
class a {
  public static $foo = 'bar';
}
class b {
  public $classname = 'a';
}
$b = new b();
```

Is it somehow (curly braces etc.) possible to access $foo directly without generating an "unexpected :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)":

```
$b->classname::$foo //should result in "bar" not in an "unexpected :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)"
```

I know and use the following workaround:

```
$c = $b->classname;
$c::$foo;
```

but I would like to know if it exists another nice way to do access $foo directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [accessing static methods using a variable class name (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059957/accessing-static-methods-using-a-variable-class-name-php)

Comment: No its no duplicate as mentioned above, since the workaround is using what is answered in the above question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like using variables variable like as

```
class a {
  public static $foo = 'bar';

  public function getStatic(){
      return self::$foo;
  }
}
class b {
  public $classname = 'a';
}
$b = new b();
$a = new a();
echo ${$b->classname}->getStatic();//bar
```

Comment: I think the point is to get 'bar' without knowing the content of property classname in b. If you need to create a new a(), what's the point?

Comment: I don't have an instance of "a" (and I can't create one because of missing constructor parameters), so your solution would not work.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the following works in PHP 7:

```
echo  $b->classname::$foo;
```

Older versions need a workaround like the one you are using (which is already the "nicest" one), because the parser worked differently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build this expression:

> $string = a::$foo;

and you can use eval this way:

```
eval('$string=' . $b->classname . '::$foo;');

print($string);
```

Comment: OP asked for a "nice" way ;-)

Comment: Yeah, well, I don't think he'll get it nicer than he already did, just offering alternatives.

Comment: ACK. But recommending `eval` goes a bit too far, don't you think?

Comment: Guess that's up to OP to "eval" (wink, wink)

Comment: I am also agreeing that eval is no nice way ;)