# Can I make an alias class name in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting static property from a class with dynamic class name in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279081/getting-static-property-from-a-class-with-dynamic-class-name-in-php)

> Take a quick look before you are going to reading my question:

In PHP we can:

Code:

```
<?php
    class Foo
    {
        const TOUCH_ME = 1;
        public function __construct()
        {
        }
    }
    $class = 'Foo';
    $object = new $class();
    $type = $object instanceof Foo;
    echo $type;//Expect to 1
?>
```

Output:

```
1
```

---

**And my question is, how can I do:**

Code:

```
<?php
    class Foo
    {
        const TOUCH_ME = 1;
        public function __construct()
        {
        }
    }
    $class = 'Foo';
    $var = $class::TOUCH_ME;
?>
```

Output:

> An error

So, how can I do that? Or am I stupid?

Comment: Upgrade to PHP 5.3 or newer and `$class::TOUCH_ME` works fine.

Comment: If you just want the constant, you don't need any elaborate workarounds or PHP 5.3. A simple `constant("$class::TOUCH_ME");` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php -r ' class Foo { const BAR = 1; } $class = "Foo"; $var = $class::BAR; echo $var; '

// outputs 1
```

I'm on PHP version 5.3, but I don't see why this wouldn't work in earlier versions of PHP unless it was an issue wrapped up with late static binding:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: http://codepad.org/a78m2rvq => You can visit this link.

Comment: As others have stated, this is an issue with your PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

only possible since PHP 5.3 see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php