# How Do I Retrieve a Static Property From a Dynamic Object in a Single Expression?

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

After swapping some of my non-static vars to static vars, I ended up with some expressions similar to the one here. This throws a syntax error, but I can't figure out why.

```
Class Bar  {
    public static $name = "bar";
}

Class Foo {
    public function getParent(){
        $this->parentClass = new Bar();
        return $this;
    }
}

$foo = (new Foo())->getParent();
echo ($foo->parentClass)::$name; //this line is throwing a syntax error

//output:
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)
```

If I assign the object to a variable, then it doesn't throw the error:

```
$class = $foo->parentClass;
echo $class::$name;
//outputs "bar";
```

I could imagine possibly running into some unintended order of operations issues, but can't figure out why it's a syntax error, and I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in a single one line expression. (Since this issue was caused by a mass find/replace, it would be nice to keep it in one line)

Comment: Which php version? I got no syntax error with php 7.2.

Comment: I'm using PHP  5.6, I've noticed that it works on PHP >7, but unfortunately our system is not on that yet

Comment: One way would be to create a method in `Bar` that returns the static variable instead of trying to access it directly. Something like this: https://3v4l.org/lKkZZ. Then you could even do it in one single line (just keep chaining after the instantiation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda ugly, but if you really need a one-liner:

```
echo get_class_vars(get_class($foo->parentClass))["name"];
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1279124/1505169)

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/qJZTg)

Comment: You're correct... it does the job _and_ is ugly :-p

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yeah, I'd go the route of assigning to a variable first myself, but I'll leave that choice up to the OP.

Comment: Y, that would probably perform a bit better as well. I haven't done any tests but I would guess that `get_class_vars()` would preform a bit worse.

Comment: And all other developers reading your code maybe want to hurt you.

Comment: @steven - So it's ugly, bad for performance _and_ your well-being? That's a metric worth taking into account. However, it does give a solution to the OP's problem. :-)

Comment: Hey, don't shoot the messenger  :-)

Comment: Well, @PatrickQ, that is quite the one liner. haha. Thanks! I guess that's all we can do for now, until I get upgraded

Comment: @Gisheri - I would actually recommend that you store it in a variable instead. That would make it way more readable. In a few months/years when you or some other developer need to do some changes in that code, you will thank me. I also doubt that any IDE would properly handle that in regards to auto complete and such.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Thanks I did take the 2 line route.

Answer (score 2):

In fact this is only possible as of PHP 7.0. The changed behaviour is not well documentated. I think it's more of a bugfix than a new feature.

However the closest solution to a "one-liner" (working in 5.6) seems to be this one:

```
$bar = (new Foo())->getParent()->parentClass;
echo $bar::$name;
```

Maybe that is not what you tried to achieve.
The important thing is that the static class is only accessable by putting it into a single variable first.

I recommend a migration to PHP7 urgently.