# Inheritance concept

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee

In Inheritance concept, i have a static method in super class and i am inheriting that class to one sub class. In that case the static method is inherited to sub class or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method is public static or protected static in the superclass it will be accessible in the subclass. So in that sense it is inherited. The code below will compile and run fine.

```
public class A {
   public static String foo() {
     return "hello world";
   }
}

public class B extends A {
   public void bar() {
      System.out.println(foo());
   }
}
```

However, this is a bad use of the term "inherited" as it is not tied to a particular instance - hence Kaleb's answer. Normal OO design does not treat static methods as inherited, and it gets very confusing, especially when you start talking about overriding them.

Answer (score 8):

Remember that static methods are not instance methods - they relate to a class and not an instance.  Since the derived class can be considered to be of the base type, you can access the static method via the derived type.

Given:

```
class A {
    public static void foo(){}
}

class B extends A {
}
```

Then:

```
B.foo(); // this is valid
```

Comment: The question was tagged Java - this looks like C++/C# to me. Hence vote down

Comment: @Nick: you voted down because he used a colon rather than the word `extends`? Really? The content is perfectly correct apart from that.

Comment: @Nick - fixed. Hard to get away from the beauty of C# :)

Comment: @Adam I always vote down if incorrect, which it was. Now it's fixed I've voted up.
@Winston - thanks for edit

Comment: @Winston - I've made the code a bit more Java code style as well

Comment: @Nick: The debate about whether or not brackets should be on their own line extends (no pun intended!) much farther back than Java ;)

Answer (score 2):

Wait, I stand corrected -- static methods ARE inherited.  Sort of.  However, they don't act like  real OO inheritance.  For example, with these classes:

```
public class Parent {
   public static void printIt() {
       System.out.println("I'm Parent!");
   }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public static void printIt() {
        System.out.println("I'm Child!");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent child1 = new Child(); 
        Child child2 = new Child();
        child1.printIt();
        child2.printIt();
    }
}
```

If you call `child1.printIt()`, it'll use `Parent.printIt()`, because child1 has been cast to a `Parent` class.  If you call `child2.printIt()`, however, it'll use `Child.printIt()`, because it's cast to a child.  So it's not really true inheritance, because overriding doesn't stick if you cast to a supertype.  Thus it's not a true polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

It is inherited, in the sense that it can be accessed as a static method of any subclass

Why didn't you try it yourself?

1. Create a `class A` with a `staticMethod()`
2. Create a `class B extends A`
3. Try calling the static method with `B.staticMethod()`

Comment: Inheritance relates specifically to instances. Static members are specifically UNRELATED to instances.

Answer (score 0):

The parent static method will be accessible in subclass, but cannot be overriden.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can inherit static methods.
But if your static method has private access modifier you can't inherit it

Answer (score 0):

Another (advanced) concept that you would probably care about here is the concept of "late static binding" - overriding static functions in child classes. Here's a question on this from the PHP world, but it applies across the board: [When would you need to use late static binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87192/when-would-you-need-to-use-late-static-binding/87351#87351)